# visualvm fails with "No jdkhome found" on Ubuntu 15.10 with Oracle JDK

Tags: java, visualvm, oraclejdk

I installed Oracle JDK from the `webupd8team/java` PPA, and then installed the `visualvm` package. When starting `visualvm`, I get the following error message:

```
[beni:~]$ visualvm
No jdkhome found
```

My `$JAVA_HOME` is set correctly to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle`.

Also, when starting `visualvm` with the `jdkhome` property set, I get the same error:

```
[beni:~]$ visualvm --jdkhome $JAVA_HOME
No jdkhome found
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`visualvm` checks the following three directories for a JDK:

- `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-$ARCH`
- `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-$ARCH` and
- `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java`

From the `/usr/bin/visualvm` start script:

```
visualvm_jdkhome=
for j in /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-$ARCH /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-$ARCH /usr/lib/jvm/default-java; do
    if [ -x $j/bin/javac ]; then
       visualvm_jdkhome=$j
       break
    fi
done
```

So make `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` a symlink to `$JAVA_HOME`, and `visualvm` will find the right JDK.

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm
sudo ln -Tsf java-7-oracle default-java
```

Comment: You need the `-T` and `-f` options of `ln` since the `default-java` symlink probably already exists. I've updated the answer accordingly. Please feel free to revert if you disagree.

Comment: Thanks Sylvain. Although from my understanding, you only get the `No jdkhome found` error if the `default-java` does not yet exist.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I've encountered that exact problem yesterday : on one machine, `default-java`  was a symlink to openjdk-7 and `visualvm`  refused to start because of that. I wasn't able to find the correct Debian-specific script managing that link (I assume there *is* such a script) -- so I've updated it manually.

Comment: Ah okay, makes sense. Let's keep it with `ln -Tsf` then. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

In my case even the symlink of default-java didn't fixed the problem.
To fix, I did:

Edited jvisualvm and add any "trash" into `jdkhome` variable

- `$ sudo vi /usr/bin/jvisualvm`

jdkhome=/tmp

Then started the program passing parameter:

- `/usr/bin/jvisualvm --jdkhome /usr/lib/jvm/myJava7`

Note: today (2016), with my version is working only with java7

**Update**:now, in 2017, using version 1.3.8, it's working with Java 8. But I needed to add `visualvm_jdkhome=/tmp`, in /usr/bin/visualvm

Comment: I got "Your are running VisualVM using an unsupported Java version: 1.8." Is this same for the upstream version?