# Unable to launch the VisualVM Launcher Plugin in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, visualvm, jvisualvm

I'm experiencing an issue launching my application with the VisualVM Launcher plugin for Intellij. The message I recieve when lauching is displayed below:

```
Error running 'Desktop': appId=81286153463824, jdkHome=null, visualVmHome=/Applications/VisualVM.app
```

I found these post that relate to this issue: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566176/visualvm-fails-with-no-jdkhome-found-on-ubuntu-15-10-with-oracle-jdk) and [here](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS725US725&ei=P5l5W9a8IO-Z_QbD8Y_gAQ&q=intellij%20Error%20running%20%27Desktop%27%3A%20appId%3D%2C%20jdkHome%3Dnull%2C%20visualVmHome%3D%2FApplications%2FVisualVM.app&oq=intellij%20Error%20running%20%27Desktop%27%3A%20appId%3D%2C%20jdkHome%3Dnull%2C%20visualVmHome%3D%2FApplications%2FVisualVM.app&gs_l=psy-ab.12...9559.9559.0.19039.1.1.0.0.0.0.92.92.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.K0GulMn5uto). Unfortunately, the problem is I can't find the scripts mentioned in the first post and I have no idea how to create the stack trace mentioned in the latter post.

I'm quite new to Intellij coming from eclipse, I don't know what details are pertinent. Below you'll find some quick facts:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-182.3911.36, built on August 6, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.13.6
```

Comment: post this as an issue to the maintainers github repository: https://github.com/krasa/VisualVMLauncher

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably (understandably) were confused about setting the location of your VisualVM executable when configuring the `VisualVM Launcher` IntelliJ plugin:

You want to located the .jar, not your Mac's executable path:

```
$ sudo find / -name "*visualvm*"
/usr/bin/jvisualvm
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVbjV.png]

Comment: I came across same problem on Windows. For Windows, ensure pointing to the exe
...\visualvm_206\bin\visualvm.exe

Answer (score 2):

MacOs

1. Install visualvm using brew:
   `brew install --cask visualvm`
2. Set visualvm path in InteliJ IDEA
   [image]